print includes garbage out in shell
I am working with Thonny - MicroPython - ESP32 processor. My print output in the shell window includes a string of � characters. I've included an image that shows my print output code and the results that appear in the shell.
Code and resulting shell output
I don't know why this stuff is appearing.
After more observation there's a pattern to when this garbage gets inserted into my output:
Display showing pattern to garbage output

Did you check whether you're using the right baud rate? The default for the ESP32 is 115200 iirc

That is the baud rate I am using. All of my print output is fine. It just has that junk inserted every now and then. The junk is always the same length. The example I included doesn't actually make that clear because of the way I was printing.

Okay, then I don't really know what could be causing that
